# List as an object field - how to handle it via Stream (Java 8)?

Tags: java-8

There is a ***Waybill*** object that has a *Set*<*Packing*> field, the ***Packing*** object has a PRICE field.
I get a *List*<*Waybill*>.
Need to calculate the total cost of all **Packing** from the entire *List*<*Waybill*>.
How it competently to make through Stream?
Thank you.

```
class Waybill {
    Set<Packing> setOfPacking;
}

class Packing {
    int PRICE;
}

List<Waybill> allWaybills = ...
```

Comment: To clarify, by "Stream" are you referring to Java's Stream API - the Java equivalent of .NET's Linq, or do you mean an actual `java.io.Stream` object you must deserialize from?

Comment: @Dai Yes, I mean java.io.Stream

Comment: @Denis - I think you mean `java.util.stream.Stream<T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.stream.*

List<Waybill> allWaybills = ...
int totalCost = allWaybills
    .stream()
    .mapToInt(w -> w.setOfPacking
        .stream()
        .mapToInt(p -> p.PRICE)
        .sum()
    )
    .sum();
```

Comment: I think you can optimise this with `flatMapToInt()` (should be able to remove one sum).

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
double total = allWaybills.stream()
    .flatMap(waybill -> waybill.setOfPacking.stream())
    .mapToInt(packing -> packing.PRICE)
    .sum();
```

I think it is easier to reason about because there aren't any multi-level stream operations.

I would be interested to see how to use flatMapToInt to replace both the flatMap and map operations with one operation without making it multi-level.

Here is a test program:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static class Packing
    {
        public int PRICE = 0;
    }

    public static class Waybill
    {
        public Set<Packing> setOfPacking = new HashSet<Packing>();
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        List<Waybill> allWaybills = new ArrayList<Waybill>();

        Waybill w1 = new Waybill();
        Packing p1 = new Packing(); p1.PRICE = 1; w1.setOfPacking.add(p1);
        Packing p2 = new Packing(); p2.PRICE = 2; w1.setOfPacking.add(p2);
        allWaybills.add(w1);

        Waybill w2 = new Waybill();
        Packing p3 = new Packing(); p3.PRICE = 3; w2.setOfPacking.add(p3);
        Packing p4 = new Packing(); p4.PRICE = 4; w2.setOfPacking.add(p4);
        allWaybills.add(w2);

        double total = allWaybills.stream()
            .flatMap(waybill -> waybill.setOfPacking.stream())
            .mapToInt(packing -> packing.PRICE)
            .sum();

        System.out.println("total = "+total);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But tell me please, what is the difference? The better flatMap ()?

Comment: @Denis I just think it is easier to understand because it isn't nested.  Probably from the JVM's point of view it is exactly the same.  Which one do you find easier to understand?

Comment: I understand both, and another) Interesting implementation is different, thank you for reacting so quickly!